# Tesseract Can not open input file[Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tesseract

I saved the [1234567890.tif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmZS.png) into /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/:

[image]

And I have set the path of the data file `export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata`. When I typed `tesseract 12345678890.tif textoutput`

error:

> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
>
> Error: Can not open input file 1234567890.tif
>
> Error during processing.

What did I missed?

[*UPDATED*] The properties of 1234567890.tif:

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/`? Which uid is trying to open the file?

Comment: @cfromme Edited:The correct error is can not open input file instead of the permission error.

Comment: Does it give you a detail what file it can not open? What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: I upadated the complete msg.the properties of that file:http://imgur.com/a/AjSav

Answer (score 0):

Try the /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/12345678890.tif textoutput

Maybe the problem is about the path.

Answer (score 0):

The tessdata directory contains language files, such as `eng.traineddata`.

You still have to give tesseract a correct path to your input file as it does not read those files from the tessdata-dir.